# gazebo unable to create glx visual

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I install ros hydro and gazebo 1.9. When I run the gazebo command to start simulator it gives error.

```
Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: aaa
Error [RenderEngine.cc:641] Unable to create glx visual
Warning [RenderEngine.cc:92] Unable to create X window. Rendering will be disabled
```

I found several solution like "configure x11" ,but it doesn't help.
How can I fix this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188818/gazebo-unable-to-create-glx-visual/) by [lifetime](https://answers.ros.org/users/10156/lifetime/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2014-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the solution ;

http://askubuntu.com/questions/475972/error-couldnt-find-rgb-glx-visual-or-fbconfig-ubuntu-12-04

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
sudo reboot
```

---

Originally posted by [lifetime](https://answers.ros.org/users/10156/lifetime/) with karma: 33 on 2014-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miliks](https://answers.ros.org/users/49104/miliks/) on 2019-11-08**:
Hi, i was facing the same issue. I followed the suggestion, but still same error. Any other suggestion? Thanks!!